Google Sheet formula to search all columns that match a specific keyword and sum values from them
I'm trying to paste a formula on cell AS2 that searches the column names on Row 1 for an occurrence of a keyword and if that column has such a keyword on its title searches Row 2 for numeric values and sums them up on said cell AS2. I would like to expand this to all my rows.
Can anyone tell me if it's possible to achieve this instead of just summing all the different columns by refering to them directly?
Thank you!

The system only allows a maximum of 5 duplicate links but there are more.  Please search the site for answers prior to posting a new question.

You're the best, thank you!
